# Is MySQL a database? or a database server? Why do we install xampp or wamp in order to access MySQL?

Tags: mysql, xampp, rdbms

I heard that MySQL is a database server. If it is a database server, then what is the need of installing other servers like xampp or lampp? Do xampp or wamp or lampp do other jobs than being a Database server?

Comment: MySQL is a database that often comes with a server installation. Xampp is a web server to host websites. Most Websites need a database

Comment: Databases/database servers (including sqlserver,oracle,postgresql,mysql etc) hold data in a secure environment (by which I mainly mean they have backup and recovery abilities) and allow you to maintain and manipulate that data (up to a point). But that's about it , if you need to do anything else with the data then you need to bolt on other software such as php,python,pentaho etc (the list is endless) Xampp,Wamp,Lamp are bundles that include apache(a web server) PHP and mysql.

Comment: If you just want to learn sql then you can just install the db server of choice with an ide of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

XAMPP, WAMP and LAMPP are all stacks for creating web solutions. The acronyms come from A Apache (web server), M MySQL or MariaDb (Database), and P for Perl or PHP for the scripting component.

MySQL itself is just a database server (RDBMS) so you would require additional components to build an overall web solution (provided in the stacks above).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your operating system, W(Windows), L(Linux) , X(All) then we have Apache, Mysql running at different ports.
PHP including the rest of your code files stored in htdocs as they have corresponding engines in relative XAMP directories (eg php.ini). All these will give you a look and feel of a typical server environment and accommodate your frameworks (laravel, noodle etc) you can't get all that from mysql server alone.